# In NoSql how to ensure uniqueness of two columns, for example Username and Email should be unique

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, redis, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Say I want to implement a simple NoSql database containing a list of users. I want both the username and the email of the user to be unique. Which NoSql database can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is valid in MongoDB.

You need to put a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on these fields:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({
  username: 1,
  email : 1
}, {
  unique: true
})
```

Whenever you try to add a document with a username and email combination that already exists, an exception will be raised. You just need to catch the exception and tell this to customer.

P.S. if you want these fields to be individually unique, you can instead ensure two indexes:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ username: 1 }, { unique: true });
db.collection.ensureIndex({ email : 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamo you can't, at least in a direct way. That's up to your model. For example, if your key is the username, and the range key is the email, you will be able to do it. However, if one of these fields are in the value, you won't be able to achieve uniqueness

Answer (score -1):

you can user the incr command on a key in redis .
you will have something like thing like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR key
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR key
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR key
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR key
(integer) 4
```

redis is very interressing database who can manage cache (like memcache but with persistence with a lot of keys types) and pub/sub.Can be very light and very effective.

I use it on a lot of case (Session, InterProcessCommunication, persistance, realtime messaging, light data storing, geopos calculation in lua,...) i love it.
 [more infomation](http://redis.io/documentation)

Comment: it's seems that's the question is changings, there was , in my remembers no mention of link with a name , just a id. probably a mistake, But I'm french , and before minus me , you could waiting for a answer to your comment or remove of my answer.... nevermind